# forward declaration with vector of class type - pointer to incomplete class type not allowed

Tags: c++, circular-dependency, forward-declaration

I have two classes, `foo` and `bar`.

foo.h `#include`s bar.h and contains a `std::vector` of pointers to `bar` objects. At some point during runtime, `bar` has to access this vector of pointers to other `bar` objects. Therefore, `foo` contains a method named `getBarObjects()` that returns the array of pointers.

Therefore, I forward declare `foo` in bar.h. I obviously also have to forward declare the method I'm using - `foo::getBarObjects()`. As this returns the array of pointers to `bar`, I get into a vicious cycle.

I cannot forward declare Bar and then simply forward declare `getBarObjects()`, as this results in "incomplete type name is not allowed".

foo.h:

```
#include "bar.h"
#include <vector>

class foo {
    public:
         foo();
         ~foo();
         std::vector<bar*> getBarObjects();
    private:
         std::vector<bar*> barObjects;
}
```

bar.h:

```
class foo;
std::vector<bar*> foo::getBarObjects();        // error, doesn't know bar at this point

class bar {
    public:
        bar(foo *currentFoo);
        ~bar();
        bool dosth();
    private:
        foo *thisFoo;
}
```

bar.cpp:

```
#include "bar.h"

bool bar(foo *currentFoo) {
    thisFoo = currentFoo;
}

bool bar::dosth() {
    thisFoo->getBarObjects();        // error, pointer to inomplete class type is not allowed
}
```

If I simply include the other way around, I'll have just the same problem in `foo` later on. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't forward declare members.

Instead, `bar.cpp` should `#include` both `foo.h` and `bar.h`.  Problem solved.

In general, if you use the sequence:

- Forward declare all class types
- Define all class types
- Bodies of class members

everything will be fine.

Comment: Meh, simple solution to a problem that seemed big. Thank you!

Comment: I have been looking for this solution for hours. Thank you!

Comment: I'd love to see what `foo.h`, `bar.h` and `bar.cpp` looks like after following this sequence.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: Just as in the question, except that the line with the error is removed from bar.h, and a line `#include "foo.h"` is added near the top of bar.cpp (at least, before the body of `bar::dosth()`.

Answer (score 8):

You don't have to include foo.h or bar.h from each other unless you're accessing the internals of either class from the other header file. Declare the classes as needed in the header files, then include both header files from your source file.

**foo.h**

```
#include <vector>
class bar;
class foo {
    public:
         foo();
         ~foo();
         std::vector<bar*> getBarObjects();
    private:
         std::vector<bar*> barObjects;
};
```

**bar.h**

```
class foo;
class bar {
    public:
        bar(foo *currentFoo);
        ~bar();
        bool dosth();
    private:
        foo *thisFoo;
}
```

**bar.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

bool bar(foo *currentFoo) {
    thisFoo = currentFoo;
}

bool bar::dosth() {
    thisFoo->getBarObjects();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to forward declare the vector in foo.h. You also return the `vector` by-value from `getBarObjects` which is possibly not what you want and the forward declaration of the member function is useless.

Also: Use header guards. Prefer the appropriate smart pointer for your situation (`std::shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`) over raw pointers. Watch out for `const`ness.

Comment: I used header guards, no worries, I just let them out here as I typed all that to avoid confusion with additional classnames and whatnot. Thanks though