# C++: can't pass an object instance to another class because of the #include loop

Tags: c++, class, include

Let's say I have 2 classses:

```
// a.h
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "b.h"

class A {
  public: void a() {
    B* b = new B(this);
  }
}

#endif


// b.h
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "a.h"

class B {
  public: B(A* a) {
     // ...
  }
}

#endif
```

This code will raise error `A has not been declared` because class A references class B, which in turn references class A that hasn't been declared in a.h yet.

So how can I pass an instance of A to B?

Comment: There are more egregious errors in the code (the `#define`s, the `new B…`).

Comment: So many duplicates: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+c%2B%2B+header+include+implementation+order

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ - forward declaration with vector of class type - pointer to incomplete class type not allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714345/c-forward-declaration-with-vector-of-class-type-pointer-to-incomplete-clas)

Comment: @KonradRudolph, why is an include guard using `#define` an error? The alternative would be `#pragma once`, but that (although widely supported and has advantages) isn't standard is it? What would be the best practice?

Comment: @Péter The code was edited, the original version used `A` and `B` as the names of the include guards …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to

1. change the pass-by-value parameter of the `B` constructor to pointer or reference*
2. move the definition of `B::B` to the cpp file (this removes any direct dependency on the definition of `A`, and allows you to
3. *forward declare* `A` in B.h :

   ```
   // b.h
   #ifndef B_H
   #define B_H

   class A;

   class B {
     public: B(const A& a) {
        // ...
     }
   }

   #endif

   // b.cpp

   #include "b.h"
   #include "a.h"

   public B::B(const A& a) {
     // ...
   }
   ```

Note that I added a `const` qualifier for the `A&` constructor parameter, as I assume you don't want to modify `a` in the constructor of `B`.

Of course, you can also play this the other way around, by moving the definition of `A::a` and the corresponding `#include "b.h"` into a.cpp.

*<sub>You should most likely do this anyway, as it is highly unlikely you wanted to pass an `A` object by value there. Passing an object by value means implicitly creating a copy of the object and pushing that onto the stack. Which</sub>

- <sub>means that changes made on the parameter object will not affect the original object, which is usually not what you would desire, thus is a source of bugs,</sub>
- <sub>includes creating and destroying a temporary,</sub>
- <sub>usually consumes much more memory than a reference / pointer,</sub>
- <sub>opens the door to [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) bugs.</sub>

Comment: This works, thank you. But when I call some method of the A class in B, I get `invalid use of incomplete type A` and forward declaration of `struct A`.

Comment: And yes, of course I meant to pass a reference, I've updated my post.

Comment: @Alex, please show us the corresponding code, marking whether it is in the .h or .cpp file.

Comment: @Alex, the `A*` in your updated code is a *pointer*, not a reference to `A`. The latter would be `A&`.

Comment: @PéterTörök: I agree with your note for the most part, however, the problem was that you said 'need', when it is in fact not necessary.  I had assumed you said it because a lot of people think that you can't pass by value if all you have is a forward declaration, which is false.  Also, there are times when you should pass by value.  Sometimes you need to make a copy of the object anyway, and the best place to do that is in the argument list to allow for move semantics(or possibly copy elision) in cases where you happen to get an rvalue.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Forgot to include "a.h" in b.cpp. Again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You move the implementation in separate files. That way you don't have to include `B.h` inside `A.h`:

```
// a.h
class A {
public: 
    void a();
};

// b.h
#include "a.h"
class B {
public: 
    B(A a) { }
};

// a.cpp
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
void A::a(){
    B* b = new B(*this); //B constructor doesn't take a pointer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you an forward-declare a class using the syntax

```
class A;
```

in your b.h file, this is enough to tell the compiler that there is a class called A that you will have references to. It does not allow you to access the internals of that class (eg you haven't told it what members it has, or how big it is), but it's enough to use as a pointer or reference.

The other thing you can do is take a look at your design and try to remove such circular dependencies.